# What timestamp format is this Sqlite column using?

Tags: sqlite

It turns out that the Notes app on an iPhone stores the notes in a sqlite database, and after a bunch of hacking, I was able to get this file onto my PC for backup and analysis. But I'm puzzled because the timestamp values are in this format, which I don't recognize:

```
-978184314.566524
394221085.203589
412276958.735525
412279753.951386
```

The first one could be some factory installed default note with a bogus timestamp. All the rest would have been made some time in the iPhone era, after 2010 say.

What format is this, and how to convert it to a human readable date and time?

Comment: looks like standard unix time expressed in fraction of a second, or you just missed to cut off those numbers after the dot while hacking this out of the iPhone... :)

Comment: I thought of that, but the numbers don't correspond to any timestamp when such notes could have been made.

Comment: yeah, I checked, 1982 is one of them, the other 2 are 1983...

Answer (score 1):

Normal Unix timestamps are based on 1970. Apparently, these timestamps use 2000 instead:

```
> select strftime('%s', '2000-01-01');
946684800
> select datetime(-978184314.566524 + 946684800, 'unixepoch');
1969-01-01 10:08:05
> select datetime(394221085.203589 + 946684800, 'unixepoch');
2012-06-28 17:51:25
> select datetime(412276958.735525 + 946684800, 'unixepoch');
2013-01-23 17:22:38
> select datetime(412279753.951386 + 946684800, 'unixepoch');
2013-01-23 18:09:13
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks.